# Passing selective data via intents

Tags: java, android

I am making a basic contacts app with 4 fields; name, number, website and location.

Now while making the entry, the checks and prompts the user to type in case they leave and number blank.

But i want web and location to be optional.
When the data exists; I want it to be passed on but when it doesn't exist, i want it to do nothing.

Here is my code.

```
if(etName.getText().toString().isEmpty() || etNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty())
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill out the necessary fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("name", etName.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("number", etNumber.getText().toString().trim());

    if(etWeb.getText().toString().trim() != null)
    {
        intent.putExtra("web", etNumber.getText().toString().trim());
    }
    if(etLocation.getText().toString() != null)
    {
        intent.putExtra("location", etLocation.getText().toString().trim());
    }
```

The problem is the code says that condition `etWeb.getText().toString().trim() != null` and `etLocation.getText().toString().trim() != null` are always True

What changes should I make?

Comment: yes ,it's will always true

Comment: How do I correct it ?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @Zoe, Thanks for the tip, I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code to check weather data is available or not.

```
if(!etWeb.getText().toString().equals(""))
{
    intent.putExtra("web", etNumber.getText().toString().trim());
}
```

Above code will check if data is present in the field.

Comment: Okay, that works, also if you could help me with the other problem, how do i get the app to do nothing if nothing was entered?

Comment: What do you mean by "do nothing" ?

Comment: I want the fields web and location to be optional, so I am passing if statements to check if they are empty or not. If they are not empty, the data is passed ahead, but if there was no data entered, it should be okay to the application, and it shouldn't crash when location button is pressed (These buttons are where the data is sent, if you wish i can add their code to the question)

Comment: please add new question and post the updated code there as well.

Comment: I made the question but turns out I can post only one question every 90 mins. I'll post the link here when I do.

Comment: Nevermind, by some trial and error, I made appropriate changes

Answer (score 1):

You should check for isEmpty(), instead of null.

Comment: I tried doing that but there is no such thing in the code completiion. Could you help mw with that ?

Comment: That's weird behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can check string is not empty instead of not null

```
if(!android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty(etWeb.getText().toString().trim())){
 intent.putExtra("web", etWeb.getText().toString().trim());
}
```

or can check

```
 if(etWeb.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0){
     intent.putExtra("web", etWeb.getText().toString().trim());
  }
```

Comment: Hey could you explain the " !android.text.TextUtils " ??. Because if I replace it with etWeb, it gives me error

Comment: TextUtils is a Utility class provided in android. You need to pass your string data to its isEmpty() function to check if its empty or not

Comment: Oh, your comment cleared up my mistake, I was replacing the Textutils to etWeb.

Comment: Also, if you could help with the part, that would be great. How do I get the application to do nothing, if nothing was entered?

Comment: FYI : getText() method will return `CharSequence` , it's will always empty even if you are not entered anything.